# How to call one button click event in another by stopping specific properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

After clicking on `btn` triggering `btn1` click event, but clicking on `btn` it is triggering `btn1` event and closing the popup but it should not how can i stop that.

While clicking on btn only form validation should happen need to stop closing fancybox.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn1').css('display','block');
    $('.btn1').trigger('click');
});

$('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    //form validation

    $.fancybox.close();

});
```

Comment: what are `btn` and `btn1`? className or id?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Missed btn and btn1 are classes

Comment: @koder what is that variable `error`? what does it hold?

Comment: If we given proper values to all the fieds, then it is error free so at that time I am closing the fancy box. it's not required removed that updated the Question little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass a parameter  while triggering click event on `btn1`.

**Javascript code:**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
   $('.btn1').css('display','block');
   $('.btn1').trigger('click', [true]);
});

$('.btn1').on('click', function(event, dontClose){
   //form validation
   if(error == 0 && !dontClose){
      $.fancybox.close();
   }
});
```

when click event is triggered automatically on `btn1`, `dontClose` will be undefined in which case depending on `error` fancy box will close.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, mean while need to know  .trigger([true]) parameter  what does it mean, can you explain, anyhow learned one new thing.

Comment: `true` is just a parameter that is passed to the click event handler in order to control the fancy box. the first parameter that any event handler would expect is a event object, hence the passed parameter will start from second parameter and not from first

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood what you need, if not tell me and i'll remove this answer.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    console.log("click btn");
    $('.btn1').trigger('click', 1);
});

$('.btn1').on('click', function(e, data){

    //form validation
    if (data != 1) {  // if event is not triggered
        $.fancybox.close();
    }

});
```

Comment: with your logic the fancy box will not close based on the errors on page, existing functionality is broken.

Comment: @dreamweiver idk, OP remove error things" on his question

Comment: well i guess he meant if there are no errors, fancy box should be closed on click on `btn1`

Comment: Yes, What @dreamweiver said is correct and also I have removed the error text it's bit confusing to viewers, Your slution is also working fine. Thnaks.